# Can I ask a question about making chocolate molds?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to make some chocolate moulds in the shape of a shop-bought chocolate bar, and thought maybe this stack would be a good place to ask about how to do that. Is this on topic for the stack?

Comment: Not wanting to send you away and depending on how you phrase it, it could be fine here (and should be explained in an answer), but have you heard of [Arts and Crafts SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/)? If you are focusing more on the mold-making than the usage, they’re probably the better fit and experts. Mods there have already seen this post and would welcome it.